# Is it possible invoke telerik radgrid.databind() from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, data-binding, telerik-grid, rad-controls

Im working in asp .net and I have a aspx page with a telerik  radgrid. Is it possible invoke radgrid.databind() from a javascript function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, take a look at [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-client-side-binding.html). I think you'll find everything you need there.

Second, your problem description was limited and didn't contain much code but maybe the following examples will point you in the right direction.

[**dataBind** - RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-gridtableview-databind.html)

> Method which will force client rebind of the grid and will refresh its
>   state when a new data source is assigned using the set_dataSource()
>   method. Meaningful in this scenario only.
>
> ```
> function assignDataSourceAndRefresh()
> {
>     var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
>     masterTable.set_dataSource(<some_data_source_of_the_specified_type_above>);
>     masterTable.dataBind();
> }
> ```

[**rebind** - RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-gridtableview-rebind.html)

```
function RefreshGrid() {
    var masterTable = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
    masterTable.rebind();
}
```

Finally, [here's an alternative suggestion:](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/invoke-a-radgrid-rebind-from-javascript.aspx#1279186)

> If you want to use the `.fireCommand(action, params)` method try this:
>
> ```
> var masterTable = $find("<%= rg.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
> masterTable.fireCommand("RebindGrid");
> ```

Comment: I am using masterTableView.set_dataSource([]); 
                                masterTableView.dataBind(); It does not replace the original records with empty array but only hide the records, why?